# Склонение дробных числительных (2)

Tags: орфография, склонение, числительные

*Утвердить численность КСП в количестве 7,5 **единиц/единицы.***
Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

1) Правильно: **утвердить численность КСП в количестве 7,5 единицы.**

Для составных чисел (число + дробь) существительное ставится в форме Р.п. ед. числа, то есть **управляет существительным не целое число, а дробь**: пять десятых частей (чего?) единицы.

Это объясняется тем, что дробь расположена ближе к существительному, чем целое число, **сравнить**: *в количестве 7 единиц и в количестве 7,5 единицы.*

Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

```
8.      Правильными являются конструкции 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), т.е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Также: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра и т.д.
```

2) **Пример**: Утвердить состав и штатную численность Контрольно-счетной палаты города Кирова в количестве **14,75 единицы.**

http://kirov.regnews.org/doc/kq/u4.htm

3) **Вопрос № 280981**

Здравствуйте, скажите как правильно написать предложение "Вес посылки составил 8.3 килограмма" или "Вес посылки составил 8.3 килограммов"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Дробные числительные употребляются с существительными в форме единственного числа: **8,3 килограмма.**

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=дробные%20числительные](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: Простите, но Вы **все время (!)** ошибаетесь в оформлении перечней. **1.** С прописной буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует цифра с точкой или прописная буква с точкой. **2. Со строчной** буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует **цифра со скобкой.** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/83-rubric-77 Ещё раз — извините...

Comment: Я не ошибаюсь всё время (только иногда), а  сообщенная Вами информация мне известна. Скобки, а не точку  я  ставлю преднамеренно, просто мне не нравится автоматическая постановка номеров, которая делается в том случае, если я поставлю точку. И деление текста на части я делаю для того, чтобы можно было его удобно и быстро прочитать, это у меня не перечень, а разбивка. Неужели это кому-то мешает, всё-таки это не книжный текст из научной монографии. Может быть, можно списать на авторское оформление?